# Nonlinear difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Maybe this is a trivial question, but how to find the general solution to the following first order difference equation?

$$
y_{t+1}=a+\frac{b}{y_{t}}
$$

Also, could someone recommend a reference textbook on difference (and possibly differential) equations? I would need a quite comprehensive text, at an intermediate level.

Thank you.

Comment: Here $a,b$ are constants independent of $t$, so an "autonomous" equation?

Comment: I'm poking around first. Assume a constant solution of the form $y_t=k$. Hence $k=a+b/k$ and it follows $k^2=ak+b$ so $k=(a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4b})/2$ are fixed points and appear to be attractive. If eventually $|y_t|>\sqrt{b}$ we have stability.

Comment: Yes, $a$ and $b$ are constants, I should have specified it.

Comment: Non linear are always hard to deal with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would write $y_t = \frac{p_t}{q_t}$, so the general step becomes

$$ \frac{p}{q} \rightsquigarrow a+\frac{bq}{p} = \frac{ap+bq}{p}$$

and the recurrence splits into two coupled *linear* ones:

$$ p_{t+1} = ap_t + bq_t $$
$$ q_{t+1} = p_t $$

Substituting the second of these into the first we get

$$ p_{t+1} = ap_t + bp_{t-1} $$

which can then be solved by standard methods.

Comment: +1 that's genius. This checks out with my work in the comments. For $a=1,b=1$ it converges to $\varphi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ which is consistent with the ratio of sequential Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Brilliant. UpVote 0 k.

Comment: this is amazing . (+1)